# How can I hide an image from the image search button?

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor

[image]

This is what I'm talking about. I want to hide some images which are not supposed to be displayed or selected from the uv editor selection, image texture selection, compositing image input or whatever option that includes the image search button. These images have a huge resolution and size as well, so when that little button is clicked, all that memory suddenly adds up; so hiding these is also supposed to not calculate them in any way.

Does anyone have an answer for this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think images shown there can be hidden to the search button... that button searches amongst images which are all part of your file! and, what you mean by "when that little button is clicked, all that memory suddenly adds up"? what you experiment? lag? crash? freeze, slowness?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/38335bdfe9d3ab688a669d9b3b20f474.mp4 Look at the memory usage, because of Blender loading up the images and previews, it rose up to 430MB, and later to 3GB, plus I don't want those images to actually display there. I don't actually know if it's possible to hide them from the image search, but a way to do it could work nicely for this.

Comment: I see memory usage rising, but as said there's no way to hide them. those seem to be all exr images... how many and how big they are? If you're experimenting lag, crash or unresponsiveness because of that you could file an issue on the bug tracker...

Comment: It was a test with HDR Panoramas that load up quite a lot of memory, they are about 6K and use around 70 MB each. There are no bugs btw, it's just the memory loading up. Tho I can kinda see why this wouldn't be possible anyway, and I found an alternative for that.

Comment: ok but why should blender take up so much space when you just "list" those images... does it free that memory later? if not, it could be a bug, imho.

Comment: The list loads up the thumbnails of those panoramas, and I think the image data itself, a lot of memory usage comes from that. Before the thumbnails load up, the memory usage stays to a low, normal level. The memory should free up, but my computer usually crashes in this case before they... load up. This isn't a bug, since it's important to see the thumbnails of the textures you want to load to find them more easily. However, there could probably be a way to use less memory since the preview uses a low res image and shouldn't load up GB of memory. A lil customizing of that would work as well